# Can Amazon Redshift UNLOAD into Parquet or Avro format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

While unloading any data from redshift generally delimiter and zipping is specified along with required arguments

Example

```
 UNLOAD ('SELECT * from  <schema>.<table_name>') 
TO '<s3_path>' 
DELIMITER AS '$' 
GZIP 
ALLOWOVERWRITE
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
escape addquotes;
```

Does redshift support the unloading in the different file-format such as Parquet or avro ?
Is redshift going to add this support of the file-format for the unload?

Answer (score 4):

Redshidt can now unload data to S3 in Parquet format:

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
FORMAT PARQUET
```

Documentation mentioned it at [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Comment: I saw today, AWS has recently added the support to unload data by specifying the format.

Answer (score 1):

The [UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) documentation does **not** show Parquet or Avro as output formats.

You could use **Amazon Athena** to convert the output from `UNLOAD` into one of those formats.